# open CV project not build

Tags: android

```
Build command failed.
Error while executing process C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\cmake\3.10.2.4988404\bin\ninja.exe with arguments {-C D:\Raju\company project\bobomusu\bobomusu\android\app\.cxx\cmake\debug\armeabi-v7a my-native-lib}
ninja: Entering directory `D:\Raju\company project\bobomusu\bobomusu\android\app\.cxx\cmake\debug\armeabi-v7a'

ninja: error: 'Libraries/libopennurbs_public.a', needed by 'D:/Raju/company project/bobomusu/bobomusu/android/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libmy-native-lib.so', missing and no known rule to make it
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your project api level to 21 in `build.gradle` then delete build directory from project and rebuild again the project